# I am using Android Studio 2022.2.1 for ATAK, and I want to attach a javadoc jar file so popups will have more info. How?

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

All documentation for how to attach a javaadoc jar file is for older version of Android Studio.

I am developing a plugin for ATAK. It has a library, main.jar, which is used by the project (but does not show in project properties or gradle files - go figure).

It also has a javadoc jar file that goes with it.

I want the javadoc jar file associated with the project or the library so I can see meaningful popup comments

I looked all over project struct dialog, could not find either the library or any way to associate javadoc with anything.